# How to extract the filename without the extension and write that to a tag using ExifTool?

Tags: linux, metadata, exiftool

I'm using [ExifTool](https://exiftool.org/) on Linux and am working with some MP4 video files. I want to add each file's respective filename as a metadata comment (using the `-Comment` tag). For example, suppose I have a file called `winter.mp4`, I want to add the comment "winter" to the file's `-Comment` metadata tag. Notice that the comment does *not* include the file's extension (i.e., it doesn't include the `.mp4`).

**How can I accomplish this?**

I tried using the command `exiftool '-Comment<FileName' 'winter.mp4'` but this includes the ".mp4" extension, so I see the `-Comment` tag populated with "winter.mp4", instead of just "winter". I tried looking for a solution online, but to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you're using exiftool ver 12.22+ and change `Filename` to `BaseName`.

`exiftool '-Comment<BaseName' winter.mp4`

If you have to use an older version, you can use regex to remove the extension

`exiftool '-Comment<${Filename;s/\.[^\.]+$//}' winter.mp4`